# Convert ManyToMany into ForeignKey (django)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a ManyToMany field in my database that I want to convert to a ForeignKey relationship. The relationships are already one-to-many, so there will be no pigeonholing.

The closest question I can find on stackoverflow is [this more complicated situation in a different framework/language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176323/splitting-a-manytomany-asociation-into-2-pairs-of-onetomany-manytoone-doctrine)

My simplified django models are shown below. The fields in question already exist in the database, and we just need to populate the DbLocation.pattern field.

```
class DbPattern(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToMany(DbLocation) #trying to remove this
    ...

class DbLocation(models.Model)
    pattern = models.ForeignKey(DbPattern) #and replace it with this
    ...
```

My naive solution is a nested for-loop. It works, but looks like it will take days to handle several million records:

```
patterns = DbPattern.objects.all()
for p in patterns:
    locs = p.locations # there ary many locations
    for l in locs:
        l.pattern = p # each location has exactly 1 pattern.
```

Is there an easy way to implement this in either Python/Django or PostreSQL that will run fast? I imagine there is a way to do this via queries. I only need to do it once.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you only need to do it once then I think your method is fine, can't say much about the time it would take, maybe you could test doing it with 1000 objects and then use this to calculate how long the entire db will take

Comment: Based on a trial run of 1000 samples, this naive implementation will take 60.55 days to update all of my data.

Comment: Nice work in answer

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get several orders of magnitude speedup with a few simple tweaks. More speedup could probably be achieved, but this is sufficient for my purposes.

Naive Code (1000 samples take 793 seconds)

```
patterns = DbPattern.objects.all()
for p in patterns:
    locs = p.locations # there ary many locations
    for l in locs:
        l.pattern = p # each location has exactly 1 pattern.
        l.save()
```

First improvement (1000 sample takes 11 seconds)

```
patterns = DbPattern.objects.all()
for p in patterns:
    locs = p.locations
    locs.update(pattern=p)
```

Second improvement (1000 sample takes 2.5 seconds)

```
patterns = DbPattern.objects.all()
[p.locations.all().update(pattern=pattern) for p in patterns]
```